# Dill keeps previous loaded session when loading new session

Tags: python, dill

I'm generating 2 session dumps with

```
import dill
a = 1234
dill.dump_session('test1.session')
```

and

```
import dill
b = 1234
dill.dump_session('test2.session')
```

Then loading them back into a module sequentially

```
import types
import dill

mod = types.ModuleType('test')
print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))

dill.load_session('test1.session', main=mod)
print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))


mod = types.ModuleType('test')
print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))

dill.load_session('test2.session', main=mod)
print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))
```

I get the following output

```
None   # a
None   # b
1234   # a
None   # b
None   # a
None   # b
1234   # a
1234   # b
```

Before the second session file is read, it clearly shows that the `mod` variable has no `a` nor `b` set. But then when reading in the `test2.session` file it suddenly sets both `a` and `b`. But only `b` was actually dumped into that file.

Is this a bug in dill or am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, the current behavior expects that the same module is passed to the `main` parameter in `dump_session()` and `load_session()`, which makes sense if you think that all the classes and functions defined in the saved module have their `__module__` and `__qualname__` attributes pointing to it.

That said, there are two issues:

1. The `main` parameter of `load_session()` is redundant, or at least should have `None` as default;
2. The current implementation of session loading is actually doing some duplicated work. It does the equivalent of the following sequence of operations:

```py
# In Unpickler.load()
dump_main = importlib.import_module("<dump_main>")
vars(dump_main).update(loaded_module_dict)  # once
# In load_session(..., main=load_main)
vars(load_main).update(vars(dump_main))  # twice
_restore_module(load_main)  # restore imported objects saved by reference (with byref=True)
```

This explains the strange outcome when saving `__main__` and restoring it in module `test`, and it's easy to fix.

What I'm not so sure is what should be the expected behavior of saving a module and restoring its contents in a different one —or if it should be allowed at all.

---

Note: if a saved module was created at runtime, it can be recreated manually before calling `load_session()`:

```py
sys.modules['name'] = type.ModuleType('name')
```

Maybe `dill` can also do it automatically somehow, but it is a potential situation for bugs if the user is expecting the module to actually exist and be imported. Would a warning suffice?

---

### Update

Here is a good example of why this usage should not to be allowed in `load_session()`:

```py
>>> class Point:
...   def __init__(self, x, y):
...     self.x = x
...     self.y = y
>>> p = Point(1, 2)
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dump_session()
```

In a different session:

```py
>>> import dill, sys, types
>>> sys.modules['test'] = test = types.ModuleType('test')
>>> dill.load_session(main=test)
>>> q = dill.copy(test.p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/pickle.py", line 1070, in save_global
    raise PicklingError(
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Point'>: it's not found as __main__.Point
```

Beyond this simple example, not respecting namespaces is a potential source for many subtle, silent bugs...

I don't know what the OP was trying to accomplish, but for simple cases he could do something like `dill.dump(vars(mod1), file)` and then `vars(mod2).update(dill.load(file))` in the other session. It would save classes by reference, but functions can be saved fully with the `recurse` option. I would at least save `{k: v for k, v in vars(mod1) if not k.startswith('__')}` instead of the whole `vars(mod1)` thought, to not mess with `mod2` attributes.

Comment: I agree... I believe the expected behavior was that `main` in `dump_session` and `load_session` should be the same.  I don't think the docs state that they should be the same... and the interface as it is now is a bit inviting to do something like the OP tried to do here.  So, as I asked... what should be the expected behavior here? Should `dill` allow the use case the OP is attempting?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import types
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> mod = types.ModuleType('test')
>>> mod
<module 'test'>
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
None
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))
None
>>> 
>>> dill.load_session('test1.session', main=mod)
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
1234
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))
None
>>> mod
<module '__main__' (<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10aa2bc40>)>
>>> mod = types.ModuleType('test')
>>> mod
<module 'test'>
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
None
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))
None
>>> 
>>> dill.load_session('test2.session', main=mod)
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('a', None))
1234
>>> print(mod.__dict__.get('b', None))
1234
>>> mod
<module '__main__' (<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10aa2bc40>)>
>>> 
>>> import __main__
>>> __main__.__dict__.get('a', None)
1234
>>> __main__.__dict__.get('b', None)
1234
>>> __main__
<module '__main__' (<_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10aa2bc40>)>
```

Note that `dill` is not loading the session into the module `test` that you created, it's loading into `__main__`. You can see that the module `__main__` is located at `0x10aa2bc40`, so it's the same module object being loaded into each time.

Is this a bug in `dill`?  I'm not sure, and would have to look at what is expected of the `main` keyword argument. It might be interesting to open a GitHub issue on `dill`, and start a discussion on what the expected behavior of the `main` arg should be... or at least to request some clarity in the docs so it's clear what the behavior should be. [NOTE: I'm the `dill` author]